# How to get flutterUI text to scale?

Tags: ios, flutter

I am trying to get my text to scale properly between a 5.5 inch display, a 6.5 inch display, and a 9.9 inch display. But the text keeps not scaling properly.

Here is what it looks like between 2 devices:[image]

[image]

As you can see the button text is fine for the larger display but the text up top is too small, and on the smaller display the text up top is perfect, but the button text is not appearing because of the size.

Here is my code:

```
Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(15),
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Expanded(
                        child: Align(
                          alignment: FractionalOffset.center,
                          child: AspectRatio(
                            aspectRatio: 1.0,
                            child: Stack(
                              children: <Widget>[
                                Positioned.fill(
                                  child: CustomPaint(
                                      painter: CustomTimerPainter(
                                        animation: controller,
                                        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                                        color: themeData.indicatorColor,
                                      )),
                                ),
                                Align(
                                  alignment: FractionalOffset.center,
                                  child: Column(
                                    mainAxisAlignment:
                                    MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                                    crossAxisAlignment:
                                    CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                                    children: <Widget>[
                                      Column(
                                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                                        children: <Widget>[ Text(
                                        "Days Left To", style: TextStyle(
                                            fontSize: 20.0,
                                            color: Colors.white
                                        ), // MAKE CHANGES HERE TO ALIGN TEXT BETTER
                                      ),
                                        Text("Reverse Climate Change:",
                                            style: TextStyle(
                                                fontSize: 20.0,
                                                color: Colors.white
                                            ),
                                        ),
                                      ],
                                      ),
                                      Text(
                                        timerString,
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                            fontSize: 112.0,
                                            color: Colors.white),
                                      ),
                                      RaisedButton(
                                        //splashColor: Colors.greenAccent,
                                        //color: Colors.white,,
                                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
                                        onPressed: (){
                                          Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=>ResourcePage()));
                                        },
                                        child: Container(
                                          //height: SizeConfig.blockSizeVertical * 9,
                                          width: SizeConfig.blockSizeHorizontal * 30,
                                          alignment: Alignment.center,
                                          decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                                            gradient: LinearGradient(
                                              colors: <Color>[
                                                Color(0xFF8A2BE2),
                                                Color(0xFF71637D),
                                                Color(0xFF8A2BE2),
                                              ],
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                                          child:
                                          Container(
                                            alignment: Alignment.center,
                                            padding: EdgeInsets.all(15),
                                            height: SizeConfig.blockSizeHorizontal * 6,
                                            //width: SizeConfig.blockSizeVertical * 20,
                                            child: AutoSizeText("Resources",
                                              style: TextStyle(
                                                //fontSize: SizeConfig.safeBlockHorizontal * 10,
                                                fontSize: 15,
                                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                                color: Colors.white,
                                                //height: SizeConfig.blockSizeVertical * 15,
                                              ),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [flutter_screenutil](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_screenutil) to make text responsive. Usage:

In `pubspec.yaml` add the `flutter_screenutil` in the dependency

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  flutter_screenutil:
```

Initialize the Screen.instance with width px and height px of the highest screen ratio you want to support inside build

Import the package `package:flutter_screenutil/flutter_screenutil.dart` and inside the build function initialize `ScreenUtil.instance` like given below:

ScreenUtil.instance = ScreenUtil(width: 750, height: 1334)..init(context);

Usage in `Text` Widget:

```
Text('Hello World', style: TextStyle(
   color: Colors.white,
   fontSize: ScreenUtil.getInstance().setSp(12)),
  ),
)
```

You can also refer this blog https://medium.com/nonstopio/let-make-responsive-app-in-flutter-e48428795476